# Menu listing vertically using css

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Following is the fiddle I have created [menu listing](http://jsfiddle.net/meetantoalphi/QKdBC/) and this shows the menu `horizontal` but I would like to display them `vertical`

the fiddle contains this code : `HTML`

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the `CSS`

```
#navcontainer ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }

#navcontainer ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #369;
}
```

how do I change that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `display:inline`, therefore causing the display to revert back to its default - `block`.

```
#navcontainer ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

[**Updated jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/KPKdn/)

Comment: @JosC thanks  and this is the one did the trick `ul li { float: left; clear: left; margin-bottom: 10px; background: #ccc }` and +1 for your post

Comment: @Anto `float:left` and making immediately `clear:left` is useless your making your `li` float and removing your `float`

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan thanks for the point but if I remove `clear:left ` than the menu is shown horisondal

Comment: @anto remove the `float:left` also

Comment: @Thirumalai murugan if I remove `float:left` the list will come centre that is not what I want :)

Comment: can you show the demo? or check my answer below this answer is that you need?

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QKdBC/3/)

remove `display:inline` and padding in `li` and a tag `text-align` would solve your problem look the change

```
#navcontainer ul li {padding:10px;}

#navcontainer ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
    width:75px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to add `display:block` that is the default - just remove `inline`.

Comment: @JoshC your correct I have modified that before you comment any way thanks for your advice